# What is the correct Firebase design for displaying the same image in multiple places

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a table view, where when a cell (category) is clicked it shows a tab bar with 2 tabs. The first tab is a camera, and the second tab is a gallery of images with some images.

The main constraint is that when an image is updated in a particular cell (category), it may belong to another category and should be updated there too.

Right now, I setup the Realtime Database and Storage as directories that mimic the categories.  When an image is updated (within a particular cell), it updates the image in Storage (by utilizing the cell's properties) and makes a pointer in the Database to the direct download link.

The issue with this approach is that it does not handle the main constraint at all, and multiple copies of the same image end up being stored.

Here's my code for uploading an image to Firebase

```
func savePhotoStorage(){
    //replace spaces with _
    let title = textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    let imageRef = storageRef.child(self.section).child(self.AU).child("Photos").child(title + ".jpg")

    if let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1){

        let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(dataImage, metadata: nil, completion : { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let downloadPath = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                self.pushtoDB(path: downloadPath,type:"Photos",title: title)
                print(metadata?.downloadURL())
            }
            else{
                print("No metadata available")
            }
        })
        uploadTask.resume()
        textField.text = ""
        //captureSession.stopRunning()
        //previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}

func pushtoDB(path : String, type:String,title:String){
    databaseRef.child(section).child(AU).child(type).child(title).setValue(path)
}
```

Here's my code for updating the gallery when an image is uploaded

```
func loadImages(){
    databaseHandle = databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? String {

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            let url = URL(string: snapshot.value as! String)
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url!, cacheKey: snapshot.value as? String)
            imageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            let label = UILabel()
            //label.text = imageArray[i]
            let title = snapshot.key.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
            label.text = title
            label.font = UIFont(name: "ScienceFair", size: 30)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            label.sizeToFit()

            let width = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width/2
            let xPosition = width * CGFloat(self.i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            label.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 10, width: label.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: label.intrinsicContentSize.height)
            label.center = CGPoint(x: xPosition+self.view.center.x, y: 30)

            self.mainScrollView.contentSize.width = self.mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(self.i+1)
            self.mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.mainScrollView.addSubview(label)
            self.mainScrollView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

            self.i = self.i+1
        }

    })
}
```

The perfect use case for me would be if there is some way to attach a listener to Firebase Storage, where if a file location gets updated to a new download link, all the children in the RealTime Database that pointed to the old download link now point to the new download link.

So far, I haven't found this type of listener, so how should I configure my storage and database so that the above can happen and I don't have to upload copies of the same image?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to have one copy of the image in storage, and simply make multiple references in your database for it, all using the same download url. You can then update them all in the database with an query like `database.ref('images').orderByChild(databaseURL).equalTo(imageDatabaseURL)`